# How to register a range of dependencies in MVVM Light SimpleIoc

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I want to register and unregister my view models in my view model locator class.

I want to have a collection of all my view models and iterate over them to register and unregister them. The methods that handle the registering are declared like this:

```
public bool IsRegistered<T>();
public void Register<TClass>() where TClass : class;
public void Unregister<TClass>() where TClass : class;
```

I have many of the sets of the following to register them:

```
if (SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<SettingsViewModel>() == false)
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingsViewModel>();
}
```

and to unregister them:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<SettingsViewModel>();
```

I want to foreach this code so I only have one place to declare my ViewModels. I can't get the syntax correct to do this.

```
//Incorrect non compiling code
foreach (Type viewModel in ViewModels)
{
    T t = viewModel.BaseType;
    if (SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<viewModel>() == false)
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<viewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example to explain what you mean?

Comment: Nevermind. I misread the question :(

Comment: does not look like a situation where you'd use generics, in first place. would it be an option to pass the type of the model class as an ordinary parameter to those three functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at SimpleIoc I conclude that there is no way to do what you want, since there is no Register method taking a Type as an argument.

If you would consider another IoC Container, below is how it would work with autofac. Note that this example makes some assumptions (filtering on namespace and every dependency has one interface), remove or change those assumptions according to your situation before you use it.

```
    var repositoryAssembly = typeof(SettingsViewModel).Assembly;
    var registrations =
        from type in repositoryAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where type.Namespace == "MyApp.ViewModels"
        where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
        select new { Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), Implementation = type };

    foreach (var reg in registrations)
    {
        container.RegisterType(reg.Implementation).As(reg.Service).InstancePerRequest();
    }
```